# varchar time to time

Tags: sql, oracle

Good day all,

How do I convert column time_code value '201834' to time in oracle sql? Haven't found much help looking on the web and playing around with it using to_date, cast, convert.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your time format?

Comment: Without knowing what time that is supposed to represent, it's rather hard to guess...

Comment: The time_code displayed above represents 08:18:34 pm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have HourMinuteSecond format and you want to cast it as DATE type. to_date does the trick.

```
select to_date(time_code, 'HH24MISS') from table;
```

You can store this as DATE in DB. (don't wory about DATE part - current date is used, just make sure when displaying you throw it away)

Comment: IMHO this is not a good idea, if you ignore the "DATE part" - it doesn't mean it's not there . What will happen if he'll try some arithmetic on this column ?

Comment: Of course that wouldn't be wise, but I understood that the question is just about casting varchar as date. This is simplest method, but whether it is usable depends on usage.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I understand what Jakub is saying as well as Cade. It is a simple method but i wanted to not have to do extra coding to remove the date part in the event i have to do arithmetic as stated by Cade.I just need to to from '201834' directly to 20:18:34 if possible.